# ACF Form not creating unique entities

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advance Custom Fields to create a new fields within the members profiles. Using the locations panel within the setting, i can target the user group and the fields i want to display (which works perfectly).

However, i am now using the `acf_form` function that allows me insert the form into a front end. I have created three test accounts, not including my admin account. Within the admin account, i upload an image and fill out one of the custom fields. When i log into the other account, those fields have already got that values i associated from the admin account.

This only happen in the front end form as when i visit the wordpress official user profile, its empty (like it should be).

```
<?php $options = array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'field_groups' => array(77),
    'form' => true, 
    'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ),
    'html_before_fields' => '',
    'html_after_fields' => '',
    'submit_value' => 'Update'
);
acf_form( $options );
?>
```

Is there any reason why it is doing that?

Comment: How are you adding fields to the user profile page? When I do it with the `current_user == logged_in` location rule the user fields show up on every single page on the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resolved the issue by calling on the `$current_user` from wordpress itself. Here is the new options

```
<?php $options = array(
    'post_id' => 'user_'.$current_user->ID,
    'field_groups' => array(77),
    'form' => true, 
    'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), 
    'html_before_fields' => '',
    'html_after_fields' => '',
    'submit_value' => 'Update' 
);
acf_form( $options );
?>
```